# Set up Swagger in a Spring Boot project in microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, swagger

I am developing a microservices project consisting of the following applications:
-Discovery Server
-Gateway
-Elemental Service (the main microservice)
-Chat Service (microservice that manages a chat in real time).

Now, I would like to set up Swagger, so that accessing the URI http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/
I can see all the microservices APIs.

I tried setting the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>         
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>       
</dependency>
```

in my project's pom.xml and in my gateway's pom.xml, but I still can't access Swagger.

If I access the Swagger page I get the 404 error.

How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we please get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The URL should typically be
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html or similar, depending on your context path and configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).